# CAML Query to Render a dates on Calendar

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to learn CAML Queries. I must render a lot of data on Calendar. I made a code, but if it has got more then 1000 elements it's doing very long about 4-5 seconds. It's longer then adding to list 1000 elements. I made a CAML Query on U2U CAML Query Builder. This is my CAML Query:

> `<Query> <Where> <And> <Lt> <FieldRef Name='Dzien' /> <Value
>   Type='DateTime'>[Today+30Day(s)]</Value> </Lt> <Gt> <FieldRef
>   Name='Dzien' /> <Value Type='DateTime'>[Today-30Day(s)]</Value> </Gt>
>   </And> </Where> </Query>`

It's good enough to very faster my code ? I'm very new on CAML. Can I have indexes on CAML like in Data Base ?

Here is my render code before CAML:

```
`protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
        SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPListItemCollection listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].Items;

            // Gdy nie ma zaznaczonej osoby to wtedy wyświetlamy wszystkie daty urlopów

            int index;

        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "<-- Wszystcy pracownicy -->" || DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "")
        {

            foreach (SPListItem olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt in listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt)
            {

                if (e.Day.Date.Date.ToShortDateString() == Convert.ToDateTime(olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Dzien"]).ToShortDateString())
                {
                    e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF0000");
                    e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
                }

            }
        }
        else

        // Renderowanie urlopu dla pojedyńczej zaznaczonej osobie
        {
            foreach (SPListItem olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt in listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt)
            {
                index = olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Pracownik"].ToString().IndexOf("#");

                if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Pracownik"].ToString().Substring(index + 1))
                {
                    if (e.Day.Date.Date.ToShortDateString() == Convert.ToDateTime(olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Dzien"]).ToShortDateString())
                    {
                        e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#F5BCA9");
                        e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
                        e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("<p style='color:blue; font-size:8px;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Kontrakt"].ToString() + "</p><p style='color:#5D198E;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"].ToString().Substring(3) + "</p>")));
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        SPWeb witryna1 = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPListItemCollection listaDniSwiatecznych = witryna1.Lists["DR2013 Święta"].Items;

        foreach (SPListItem olistaDniSwiatecznych in listaDniSwiatecznych)
        {
            // Wyświetlenie na kalendarzu weekendów
            if (e.Day.Date.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday" || e.Day.Date.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
            {
                e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF9900");
                e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
            }

            // Wyświetlenie na kalendarzu dni świątecznych
            if (e.Day.Date.Date.ToShortDateString() == Convert.ToDateTime(olistaDniSwiatecznych["Data"]).ToShortDateString())
            {
                e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFF00");
                e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("<p style='color:red; font-size:8px;'>" + olistaDniSwiatecznych["Data"].ToString().Substring(0, 10) + "</p>")));
            }

        }
} // Koniec protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
```

` **It's render after change month of Calendar about 4-5 secounds**

Comment: Grzegorz, firstly its CAML and not CALM :).. Also, I didn't see any SPQuery object in your code.. where do you wish to run this query??

Comment: It is Upper.Before code: `<Query> <Where> <And> <Lt> <FieldRef Name='Dzien' /> <Value Type='DateTime'>[Today+30Day(s)]</Value> </Lt> <Gt> <FieldRef Name='Dzien' /> <Value Type='DateTime'>[Today-30Day(s)]</Value> </Gt> </And> </Where> </Query>`

Comment: I don't add SPQuery, because I don't know where schould I add it.

Comment: Where are you binding Calendar1? DataSource for Calendar1?

Comment: Only on Render procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no project is selected your CAML query should only select by date something like:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='Dzien' />
    <Value Type='DateTime'>2012-10-22T00:00:00Z</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

When a project is selected it should do the query on date and project like:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Dzien' />
      <Value Type='DateTime'>2012-10-22T00:00:00Z</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Pracownik' />
      <Value Type='Lookup'>ProjectName</Value>
    </Eq>
  </And>
</Where>
```

I'm not entirely sure how you want your background color to work. But this should give you the data as fast as possible:

```
    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
        if (e.Day.Date.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || e.Day.Date.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF9900");
            e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
        }

        string DateOnlyQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Eq></Where>";
        string FullQuery = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Pracownik' /><Value Type='Lookup'>{2}</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
        string dateISO = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToUniversalTime());

        SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;
        var query1 = new SPQuery();
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "<-- Wszystcy pracownicy -->" || DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "")
        {
            query1.Query = String.Format(DateOnlyQuery, "Dzien", dateISO);
        }
        else
        {
            query1.Query = String.Format(FullQuery, "Dzien", dateISO, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
        }
        query1.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Kontrakt' /><FieldRef Name='Procenty' />";
        query1.ViewFieldsOnly = true;

        SPListItemCollection listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].GetItems(query1);


        // Gdy nie ma zaznaczonej osoby to wtedy wyświetlamy wszystkie daty urlopów 
        foreach (SPListItem olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt in listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt)
        {
            e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#F5BCA9");
            e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("<p style='color:blue; font-size:8px;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Kontrakt"].ToString() + "</p><p style='color:#5D198E;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"].ToString().Substring(3) + "</p>")));
        }

        SPWeb witryna1 = SPContext.Current.Web;
        var query2 = new SPQuery();
        query2.Query = String.Format(DateOnlyQuery, "Data", dateISO, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
        query2.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Data' />";
        query2.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
        SPListItemCollection listaDniSwiatecznych = witryna1.Lists["DR2013 Święta"].GetItems(query2);

        foreach (SPListItem olistaDniSwiatecznych in listaDniSwiatecznych)
        {
            e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFF00");
            e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("<p style='color:red; font-size:8px;'>" + olistaDniSwiatecznych["Data"].ToString().Substring(0, 10) + "</p>")));
        }

    }
```

Comment: How can I learn CAML ?

Comment: Its works very fast, but this isn't show me when I select <==Wszyscy pracownicy ==> thats caled all workers.

Comment: Make sure the text in the dropdown and the if statement are exactky the same (including spaces and - vs =)

Comment: I look on it, but in Your code isn't his color of days for all workers - Pracownicy
Red color: Wchich should Color all workers days first off for Red :)
`
            foreach (SPListItem olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt in listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt)
            {

                if (e.Day.Date.Date.ToShortDateString() == Convert.ToDateTime(olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Dzien"]).ToShortDateString())
                {
                    e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF0000");
                    e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
                }`

Comment: I see there isnt a red color, and only one worker color :)

Comment: I will try red color to this, because all left is working good :)

Comment: I want very much to learn CAML :) Its very very fast :) Thanks :)

Comment: I done it :) I coped two times this in each if: